# Stored procedures analysis

Tags: stored-procedures, statistics, teradata, usage-statistics

Could you please advise the query to understand which tables the stored procedures touch in **Teradata** during some period of time? Are there any metadata which stores this information? Ideally would be great to receive the stats for all stored procedures/tables in one result, but any answer is appreciated. Thank you in advance.
The problem is - analysis of all tables usage/dependencies for migration planning.

Comment: For SPs the easiest way is DBQL, using WITH OBJECTS (maybe NO COLUMNS option to save space)

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example